# Simple Python SQL Query

Tags: python, sql

Simply trying to build a sql query to execute from python. Getting SQL syntax error.

```
for elem in phraseList:
    cursor.execute("SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(ID) FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%PRT%' \
    AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%COND%' \
    AND PHRASE LIKE (%s)),(elem)")
```

However note that when I execute the following (it works perfectly fine):

```
for elem in phraseList:
    cursor.execute("SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(ID) FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%PRT%' \
    AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%COND%' \
    AND PHRASE LIKE '%dmg'")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `elem` a *separate parameter*, not part of the query string:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(ID) FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%PRT%' \
    AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TEST.NERD WHERE LABEL LIKE '%COND%' \
    AND PHRASE LIKE %s", (elem,))
```

That last parameter needs to be a tuple with one element, and to create one of those you need to have that one comma there too.

Comment: I have posted another problem that I am facing here now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435676/python-sql-valueerror . Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't catch on to the `%PART%`, etc. problem there; should have realized this could be the MySQLdb adapter. Answered there.