# Python SQL ValueError

Tags: python, sql

I am getting the following error:

```
query=query%db.literal(args)
ValueError: Unsupported Format character 'P' (0x50)
```

Here is my query being executed from python (note that phraseList is a list)

```
for elem in phraseList:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(CASEID) FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE '%PART%' \
    AND CASEID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CASEID FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE '%CONDITION%'\
    AND PHRASE LIKEPHRASE LIKE %s""",(elem,))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLdb overloads the Python string formatting syntax, and the `%P` part of `%PART%` is seen as a string formatting expression.

To prevent this you need to double the character to `%%`:

```
for elem in phraseList:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(CASEID) FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE '%%PART%%' \
    AND CASEID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CASEID FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE '%%CONDITION%%'\
    AND PHRASE LIKEPHRASE LIKE %s""",(elem,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what made the error disappear:

```
for elem in phraseList:
    part='%part%'
    condition='%condition%'
    query="SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(CASEID) FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE %s \
    AND CASEID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CASEID FROM TEST.NER WHERE LABEL LIKE %s \
    AND PHRASE LIKE %s)"
    params=(part,condition,elem)
    cursor.execute(query,params)
```

Comment: Now `part` and `condition` are interpolated without `%` wildcards and have been lowercased. Although using them as SQL parameters would help here, that is not going to work if you change the meaning.

Comment: @Martjin: Actually now it works even with part='%part%' as above

Comment: You still are matching against lowercase text instead of uppercase. The meaning is different from the original.